# RavenDB unable to import .ravendump export file

Tags: json, database, json.net, ravendb, jsonreader

Me and my co-workers are using RavenDB (currently Stable Build 3800). When one of us creates an export of our Develop Server's Database (with or without enabled Indexes), my co-workers are able to import it locally without a problem, but I'm getting the same error every time.

The error is:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected **':'** but got: ...

A few things to note about this error:

- The same .ravendump file always gives the same invalid character error on the same Documents-nr.
- When my co-worker creates a new export .ravendump-file again, both the Documents-nr and invalid character is different.
- The **`:`** in the error is the random character. I've had the error with a `.`, a `/`, the letter `B`, etc. with different .ravendump export files.
- We currently have a database of just over 200,000 documents. Same as the random character, the Document-nr where it gives the error also varies PER FILE. I could import the same file 5 times in a row, and every time it gives the error at the same Document-nr. But when I try a different export-file, it stops at a different nr. Sometimes 78.848, sometimes 159.744, etc. **Both the character and the Document-nr it stops are random per .ravendump file.**

I've tried removing RavenDB a couple of times, I've tried updating from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 (kinda unrelevant perhaps, but since my co-workers are using Windows 7 and 10 and I was the only one with 8.1, we just tried updating to 10 Enterprice). I've also tried with or without disabled indexing when importing. This afternoon I'm gonna try adding some more RAM to my laptop if my boss still has some lying around (currently I have 10MB, and my co-workers have 10, 14 and 16). Although when I import the file I'm at a steady 70-80% Memory..

My co-workers can import the exact same .ravendump file without a problem, but I'm unable to. Is there some thing that could cause this difference? We all use Raven Build 3800, but perhaps the Newtonsoft version is different, or the JavaScript version, or whatever. Some difference that causes this problem..

So, currently I'm stuck. I'm able to use a work-around for this: Getting the Production Database (instead of the Develop one) and run all the updates we did so far on Develop (Patches, Projections, and what not) locally, which takes about the entire day to complete. I'm probably gonna start doing that while waiting for an answer. Still, it's a very annoying problem that I've had multiple times already during the development of this project, and since the database is growing, I can't spend an entire day every four-seven days when we've made some changes developing which requires a database-reset..

I've searched a bit for this issue and I've seen a few other people with the same problem, but no real solution in my case. One had a different server database version in comparison to locally, but we have the same 3800 build.

Here below is a screenshot of the error and the entire stacktrace, although it's a kind of irrelevant error since my co-workers can import the exact same file with the exact same RavenDB version without a problem.

[image]

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: /. Path 'Docs[79699].Tussenpersonen[81].Id', line 12179618, position 2.
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseUnquotedProperty() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 899
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 851
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 396
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 314
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 261
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJArray.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJArray.cs:line 139
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 235
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJToken.ReadFrom(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJToken.cs:line 178
>      at Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.d__a1.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.cs:line 1211
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.<>c__DisplayClass70.b__69() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.cs:line 796
>      at Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.d__72.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.cs:line 863
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.d__5e.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.cs:line 695
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Raven.Database.Server.Controllers.StudioTasksController.<>c__DisplayClassf.<b__b>d__14.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Controllers\StudioTasksController.cs:line 173
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: /. Path 'Docs[79699].Tussenpersonen[81].Id', line 12179618, position 2.
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseUnquotedProperty() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 899
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 851
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 396
>      at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 314
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 261
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJArray.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJArray.cs:line 139
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 235
>      at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJToken.ReadFrom(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJToken.cs:line 178
>      at Raven.Abstractions.Smuggler.SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.d__a1.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Smuggler\SmugglerDatabaseApiBase.cs:line 1211<---

Comment: It is possible that this is something on your machine? Collation? regional settings?

Comment: The dump file is just gzip, you can extract that and look at the data yourself to see if there is something funny there.

Comment: It most likely is something on my machine, since my co-workers and I have the same RavenDB build. I just have no idea what..